# Cannot access 'productsForSale' before initialization

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone please point me in the right direction,

I'm trying to make my first cart in JS and after looking online I can't see where I am going wrong, I have looked online but can't see how to fix it, so I hope to get some guidance, many thanks

```
let productsForSale = [
    ['/images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg', 'Fall Limited Edition Sneakers', 125.00, ' ', '/images/icon-delete.svg']
    ['/images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg', 'Fall Limited Edition Sneakers', 125.00, ' ', '/images/icon-delete.svg']
    ['/images/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg', 'Fall Limited Edition Sneakers', 125.00, ' ', '/images/icon-delete.svg']
    ['/images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg', 'Fall Limited Edition Sneakers', 125.00, ' ', '/images/icon-delete.svg']
];
function addProducts() {
    let main = document.getElementsById(productsForSale);
    // All product elements to be addedd to cart

    let productListItem = document.createElement('li');
    let productImg = document.createElement('img');
    let productTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    let productPrice = document.createElement('p');
    let productAmount = document.createElement('p');
    let productDelete = document.createElement('img');

    // Push product elements into HTML
    main.appendChild(productListItem);
    productListItem.appendChild(productImg);
    productListItem.appendChild(productTitle);
    productListItem.appendChild(productPrice);
    productListItem.appendChild(productAmount);
    productListItem.appendChild(productDelete);

    // Edit pushed element info from array
    productImg.src = productsForSale[0][0];
    productTitle.innerHTML = productsForSale[0][1];
    productPrice.innerHTML = '$' + productsForSale[0][2];
    productAmount.innerHTML = '$' + productsForSale[0][3];
    productDelete.innerHTML = productsForSale[0][4];


}

  <!--Cart Start-->
  <div class="cart" id="cart" onload="addProducts()">
    <h3>Cart</h3>
    <hr>
    <ul id="products">
  
    </ul>
    <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
  </div>
  <!--Cart end-->
  <!--Button start-->
  <form>
    <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
    <input type="number" id="number" value="0" />
    <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
  </form>
  <button onclick="addProducts()" class="add_to_cart_btn"><img src="/images/white-icon-cart.svg" alt="">Add to cart</button> 
<!--Button end-->
<script src="/js/index.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update the code you’ve shared here such that it meets the requirements of a [mre], preferably as a runnable snippet?

Comment: **productsForSale** is an array holding your products. However, this line **document.getElementsById(productsForSale);** is trying to refer to the entire array instead of the ID of an element in HTML. It looks like that is meant to be the HTML element where the cart will be shown?

Comment: Try declaring the variable with const or var instead of let, I think the problem is due to let variables initialization.

Comment: You also forgot the comma after the end of each array in **productsForSale **.  and its **getElementById** not **getElementsById**